# Android CameraX: Cannot convert ImageProxy to Bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I am using `ImageCapture` to take a picture using the `takePicture` function with `OnImageCapturedCallback` like this:

```
imageCapture.takePicture(
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
    object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
            // ...
            image.close()
        }

        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
            super.onError(exception)
        }
    }
)
```

Now, in my screen, I have a state to hold the image:

```
var image: Bitmap? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
```

However, when I use `toBitmap()` on the image, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect image format of the input image proxy: 256, only ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 and PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 are supported
```

And this happens before I attempt to assign the image to the state holder (I am trying to convert the image to a bitmap in the callback).

Anyone know what is going on here? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently the method only works with ImageAnalysis output.  Could you file a feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=618491&template=1257717